# How does TVJS detect swipes on the Apple TV remote?

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, tvml, tvjs

I am building an app using TVJS and TVML for Apple TV. Is there an event to help me detect when the user has swiped the siri remote's touchpad? When I'm showing an image full-screen and the user swipes, I want to move to the next/previous image. But I can't seem to find any event for detecting these swipes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can 'detect these swipes' and react with them manually, TVML and TVJS use standard templates and have particular interactive components that can be laid out on screen and then the Apple TV handles moving between those elements by interpreting the commands from the control.

TVJS only allows you to listen to a limited number of events

```
enum TVElementEventType : Int {
    case Play
    case Select
    case HoldSelect
    case Highlight
    case Change
}
```

You should be able to use the functionality you described by using the correct templates or elements, such as the [OneUp template](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/OneupTemplate.html).

Without knowing how you've implemented this so far, there isn't anything else I can recommend. please show the code you are using for more accurate advice